# I have an excel document that will not print the lines with a some cells being grey

Tags: printer

If I pick black and white under sheet/page setup when I'm trying to print it will print the lines. If I don't pick black and white I the grey cells show up but not the lines.

Comment: Do you mean borders? Do you see them on the screen? Which version of excel do you print from?

Answer (score 1):

On the Page Layout ribbon in the Sheet Options box there are checkboxes for Gridlines (View and Print).  If you click the checkbox for Print, you should see your cell borders when you print.

Comment: Yes I mean borders, I do see them on the screen, and I'm using 2010.

Comment: I don't want see the grid lines. It's not letting me print the borders and grey shading on one document

Comment: Could you have that sheet set to print black & white?  Click the Page Layout ribbon, then Page Setup (lower right), then the Sheet tab.  See if under the Print section the checkbox for Black and White is checked.  If so, uncheck it.

Comment: When I do that, I lose all my borders.

Comment: I get my grey back but lose my borders.

Comment: Might have to reset borders.

Answer (score 1):

If the lines are very thin, there is no guarantee that a printer will print them. The problem is that the printer can only print black. If the line is grey, the printer has to print some black dots interspersed with white (no dots). The lighter the grey, the more white is needed. Most printers do not guarantee that a single-pixel wide line will print, they usually need a width of a couple of pixels. Depending on just where the line is, that may mean it "falls between the dots".

Try selecting a thicker line, and see if that prints.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to Printer Properties and disable "Print Optimizations" and "Advanced Printing Features" to make it work